# C# Json Convert any dynamic object to key value pairs not class

Tags: c#, json

i have a Json

```
{
   "test1.png": "123",
   "image.png": "456",
   "pdffile.pdf": "789"
}
```

how can i convert to C# dictionary or table

Comment: Did you review [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
string serializedDic = @"{
   ""test1.png"": ""123"",
   ""image.png"": ""456"",
   ""pdffile.pdf"": ""789""
}";

Dictionary<string, string> dict = 
  JsonSerializer
  .Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(serializedDic);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Newtonsoft Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) library.

First, create your own class, with 3 properties name it as you want. Add JsonPropertyAttribute with name exactly same as 3 json property.

Then, just Deserialize your json file to get your object.

Answer (score 0):

Use Newtonsoft Json library

```
string json = @"{
    "test1.png": "123",
    "image.png": "456",
    "pdffile.pdf": "789"
}";

var dic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).